# How to pick a random number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Getting random value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/javascript-getting-random-value-from-an-array)

I have a list of ten items.

```
ar = [112,32,56,234,67,23,231,123,12]
```

How do I choose an item randomly with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ar = [112,32,56,234,67,23,231,123,12];
var randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * ar.length);
var randomValue = ar[randomKey];
```

Check out the documentation on the `Math` object; https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

You could easily abstract this into a nice function:

```
function getRandom(array, getVal) {
    var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

    if (getVal) {
        return array[key];
    }

    return key;
}
```

Then you'd call it like `getRandom(ar)` to get a random key in the array, and `getRandom(ar, true)` to return a random value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

well something like

```
var randnum = Math.floor ( Math.random() * ar.length ); 
val random = (ar[randnum]);
```